# Find values that are not in every row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that contains users in each column. Below each user lists groups that they are in.

I want to highlight values that are not in every column.

- If a user is part of a group that everyone is a part of, that group would not be highlighted.
- If there was even one person who wasn't part of that group as well, that group would be highlighted.

Example.

Say there are 3 columns: A, B, C.

- Column A has values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 listed below it.  Each number in a different row
- Column B has values 1, 2 ,4, 5 listed below it.
- Column C has values 1, 2, 4, 6, 7 listed below it.

In this example

- In Column A, 3 and 5 would be highlighted.
- In Column B, 5 would be highlighted.
- In Column C, 6 and 7 would be highlighted.

Because each of those numbers are not listed every column.

Comment: This can be done with conditional formatting, is vba a necessity?

Comment: How is done with conditional formatting, not seeing the way myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you can do this using Conditional Formatting using the following logic:

Just for the sake of example, suppose your data is in the range `A1:H20` with, as you said, each column being a new user and the first row `A1:H1` being user names.

What this tells us:

`COUNTA($A$1:$H$1)` = Number of users

`COUNTIF($A$1:$H$20,A2)` = Number of times the value in A2 appears in your dataset

Therefore if `COUNTIF($A$1:$H$20,A2) < COUNTA($A$1:$H$1)`, that means the value in `A2` does not appear in each column (otherwise they woud be equal). (Also note that this is based on the assumption that you can't have a value appearing twice in a given column!).

At this point, it's a simple conditional formula.

Hope this explains it well enough.

Comment: I like it!  I think have that working now. thank  you for this! Wish I could give you an up rep but it doesn't let me yet...

Comment: @Weavs, just select the solution as an answer if it works for you - That way people who find this question in the future know it worked and it'll also start raising your reputation. Glad it worked for you!